# In a triangle $\Delta ABC$, let $X,Y$ be the foot of perpendiculars drawn from $A$ to the internal angle bisectors of $B$ and $C$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In a triangle $\Delta ABC$, let $X,Y$ be the foot of perpendiculars drawn from $A$ to the internal angle bisectors of $B$ and $C$. Prove that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$.

It works for an equilateral triangle because the angular bisector is also the perpendicular bisector.

I tried drawing a diagram to get some idea,

[image]

To prove that $XY$ is parallel to $BC$, i need to show that $\angle AFG=\angle AXY$ and $\angle AYF=\angle AGF$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $CX$ is a bisector and $AX\perp CX$, $X$ is the midpoint of $AF$.
In a similar way we have that $Y$ is the midpoint of $AG$. By Thales' theorem, $XY\parallel FG$, hence $XY\parallel BC$.

Comment: Can you show how "$X$ is the midpoint of $AF$"?

Comment: @AdityaDev: $CXA$ and $CXF$ are congruent by $SAA$, hence $AX=XF$.

Comment: Which two sides are equal? The triangle is not equilateral. Although it looks like one.